# How to filter the get api request

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i want to retrive data with a filter in mongod. other than find by id is there any way to retrieve by a value

```
 this.retrieveByID = (id)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        Todo.findById(id).then((data)=>{
            resolve({status:200,message:data});
        }).catch((err)=>{
            reject({status:500,message:'No data to be found. Error: '+err});
        })
    });
};
```

this is my retrive by id method i want to pass my parameter as {value:value} along with the route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongodb provides other query methods for search like `Collection.findOne()`, `Collection.find()`, `Collection.findById()`.

Preferably, you can write a generic function to search your database by query.

```
 // for single document
 this.retrieveOne = (query)=>{
    if(!query){
        query = {};
    }
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        Todo.findOne(query).then((data)=>{
            resolve({status:200,message:data});
        }).catch((err)=>{
            reject({status:500,message:'No data to be found. Error: '+err});
        })
    });
};

    // for list of documents
 this.retrieveMany = (query)=>{
    if(!query){
        query = {};
    }
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        Todo.find(query).then((data)=>{
            resolve({status:200,message:data});
        }).catch((err)=>{
            reject({status:500,message:'No data to be found. Error: '+err});
        })
    });
};
```

and you can make use of the function

```
retrieveOne({id: "YOUR_UNIQUE_ID"});
retriveOne({name: "YOUR_NAME"});
retrieveMany({age: { $gte: 20 }});
retrieveMany({deleted: false, male: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using Mongoose. You can use `findOne` or `find` method to retrieve data by field value.
Example -

```
Todo.findOne({type: 'phone'})
```